# Is there any way to get Die Hard: Nakatomi Plaza's files w/o inserting a disc?

Tags: die-hard-nakatomi-plaza

I just recently bought a GeForce GTX 970 and Die Hard: Nakatomi Plaza. The problem is, my 970 was too long for my computer and my CD drive had to be removed to make space for my card. I have the original Sierra PS1 looking disc case with the serial key and such already. Is there a way to just get the files?

Comment: The game's copy protection probably requires that you have the disc in the drive while you play the game. If it doesn't you can just temporarily connect your optical drive to your computer, letting it sit somewhere outside of the case (or maybe in), and install the game that way.

Comment: NEVER, EVER post your serial keys for games online. NEVER. People will take it and you will use up all your activations in no time. Same applies to passwords, credit card numbers (unless it is a shop interface you trust) and all other sorts of personal information.